# Build an iOS app for web-app written using the Ruby on Rails framework

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webserver

I am planing to build an iOS application for a web application that is Written using the Ruby on Rails framework.
Right now I made all the UIs needed for the iOS app. But I am still trying to figure out how am I going to make the iOS app talk to the web-server to get and set the data.
is there like a tutorial that I can follow to understand the idea of the relationship between them inside Xcode project.
I am not familiar with ruby on rails framework.
I just need an explanation for how to make iOS client for web application.

Comment: I did something similar to this, but I connected iOS and web app with an API, using the API I could get and set the data.

Comment: was it easy or too long? and what did you use?

Comment: Stack is not the best place to ask questions like that but I see there's a lot of great resources online! https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ios%20app%20with%20rails%20backend

Comment: I used [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) in iOS to parse all JSON from API. In my case create the API was the hard part.

Comment: I found this, it may help someone https://maniacdev.com/2012/05/library-for-easily-working-with-ruby-on-rails-apps-with-objective-c-code-generation

Comment: Thank you everyone! I will look deep on the search that Michal provide.